# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, popup, alert

I am trying to display **popup** in asp.net **on button click.**

```
void Btn_Click(Object sender,EventArgs e)
{
 string message = "**System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.Exception: ::1@100.44.57.72 you are not authorized at EndPoint.Common.AuthenticateExt`(String uniqueKeyForLog, QueryLimitControlFor product) in d:\Builds\PROD\EndPoint\PROD - 5 EndPoint\src\EndPoint\Common.asmx.cs:line 141 at EndPoint.Common(ExtendConfirmParameters ConfirmParameters) in d:\Builds\PROD\EndPoint\PROD - 5 EndPoint\src\EndPoint\Common.asmx.cs:line 96 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---**"


dialog(this.Page, "Error", message , 400);

}



public void dialog(Page page, string title, string message, int width)
{

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, this.GetType(), "dialog", "$('body').append($('<div>').attr({id:'dialog',title:'" + title + "'}));$('#dialog').html(' <style>  .no-close .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {  display: none;}</style><p>" + message + "</p>');$('#dialog').dialog({autoOpen: false,width: " + width.ToString() + ",modal: true,dialogClass: 'no-close',buttons: [{text: 'Okay',click: function() {$( this ).dialog( 'close' );$('#dialog').remove()}}]});$('#dialog').dialog('open');", true);

}
```

**Question:**

If i try to display below **message** in dialog

```
**System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.Exception: ::1@100.44.57.72 you are not authorized at EndPoint.Common.AuthenticateExt`(String uniqueKeyForLog, QueryLimitControlFor product) in d:\Builds\PROD\EndPoint\PROD - 5 EndPoint\src\EndPoint\Common.asmx.cs:line 141 at EndPoint.Common(ExtendConfirmParameters ConfirmParameters) in d:\Builds\PROD\EndPoint\PROD - 5 EndPoint\src\EndPoint\Common.asmx.cs:line 96 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---**
```

I get below exception :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

Which character is unexpected in above message ?

How can i solve problem in asp.net.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have some invalid escape sequences:

```
d:\Builds\PROD\EndPoint\PROD
```

Add an ampersand (@) to the front of your string:

```
string message = @"**System.Web.Services.Pro....
```